# ParserError pragma solidity ^0.4.21

Tags: blockchain

thank you so much for your help
I really appreciated 
this contract give me error in the line with (length)
"ParserError: Expected primary expression.
returns candidate.length"

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Election {

    struct Candidate {
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    struct Voter {
    bool authorized;
    bool voted;
    uint vote;
    } 
    address public owner;
    string public electionName;

    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;
    Candidate[] public candidates;
    uint public totalVotes;

    modifier ownerOnly() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function Election(string _name) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        electionName = _name;
    }

    function addCandidate(string _name) ownerOnly public {
        candidates.push(Candidate(_name,0));  
    }

    function getNumCandidate() public view returns(uint){
        returns candidates.length;
    }  

    function authorize(address _person) ownerOnly public{
        voters[_person].authorized = true;
    }

    function vote(uint _voteIndex) public {
        require(!voters[msg.sender].voted);
        require(voters[msg.sender].authorized);

        voters[msg.sender].vote = _voteIndex;
        voters[msg.sender].voted = true;

        candidates[_voteIndex].voteCount +=1;
        totalVotes +=1;
    }

    function end() ownerOnly public {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a function's returns values, you have to use `returns`.

```
functions getNumCandidates() public view returns(uint)
```

However when you actually return the values, you have to use `return`.

```
{
    return candidates.length;
}
```

Hence your code should look like:

```
function getNumCandidate() public view returns(uint){
    return candidates.length;
}
```